# Google Chrome incognito (private/anonymous browsing) not available in Google Workspace (GSuite) account

Tags: g-suite, google-chrome, privacy

Recently, `incognito` mode disappeared in *Chrome* while signed-in as *Google Workspace* account (signed-in as regular gmail account has been working just fine).

So I did an obvious check on policies ([chrome://policy/](http://chrome://policy/)), everything looked just fine:

[image]

So I got quite confused and had started to Google around and came to this (https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=IncognitoModeAvailability):

[image: 1 means disabled - ?!]

If anybody from Google is reading this, please... **why on Earth an attribute called "*...Availability*" set on "*1*" means DISABLED?!** I consider it highly non-standard and counter-intuitive.

Anyways, we've browsed through our GPO in AD and found nothing.

So the *Google Admin*... And indeed, there is a manual change which has to be made (see below in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution,
go to https://admin.google.com/ac/chrome/settings/user and change manually "Incognito mode" to `Allow`.

[image]